# RN perf question: Bind early and don’t create functions inside render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native and react in general, I was reading this article here where I stumbled upon this:

Avoid doing this inside render.

```
<Text onPress={ () => this.doWork() }>Do Some Work</Text>
```

Also, avoid this.

```
<Text onPress={ this.doWork.bind(this) }>Do Some Work</Text>
```

Because render is often called, and every time you do any of the two things above, it creates a new function, it is not recommended that way. If you want to pass arguments to doWork function, create a child component and pass the function as a prop, simple.

I'm using functional components instead of classes but first example is pretty much how I handle onPress functions, is this bad? In my components I waill have something like this in the returned view:

```
<Text onPress={ () => doWork() }>Do Some Work</Text>
```

and in my logic:

```
const doWork = () => { //do stuff}
```

Is this the proper way? if not, what is the proper way to define functions and handle button presses in a performant way.

I also tried this way earlier but the function will fire many MANY times for some reason, can someone explain why?

```
<Text onPress={ doWork() }>Do Some Work</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

When `react` render you create a new function and call the handler in it. It's useless. Moreover, you do not need to pass parameters to the handler in this example.

Therefore, there is no point in using `onPress = {() => doWork ()}`. Just use `onPress = {doWork}` instead.

> Is this the proper way? if not, what is the proper way to define functions and handle button presses in a performant way.

Yes, you defined the handler correctly, you just need to fix its usage.

And in this example, `onPress = {doWork ()}` you immediately call the function, which causes it to be called every time the component is rendered, you shouldn't do that.

So, declare handlers in this way:

```js
const doWork = () => { 
  //do stuff 
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<Text onPress={doWork}>Do Some Work</Text>
```

If you need to pass parameters to handler, then there are 3 options:

**Option 1** - Create anonymous function

```js
<Text onPress = {() => doWork(payload)}>Do Some Work</Text>
```

**Option 2** - Use bind

```js
<Text onPress = {doWork.bind(this, payload)}>Do Some Work</Text>
```

**Option 3** - Use data attributes

Limitations:

1. Won't work in React Native
2. You need to pass only the DOM to the element, it won't work on components

```js
const handleClick = (e) => {
  // e.target.dataset.payload <= "payload"
}

...
<button data-payload="payload" onClick={doWork}>Do Some Work</button>
```

If you want to read about the accepted conventions for naming handlers in React, you can read [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/handy-naming-conventions-for-event-handler-functions-props-in-react-fc1cbb791364).

Comment: I see, what if I want to pass a parameter/s to my function?

Comment: @gabogabans, I gave a more detailed answer ;)